# Cannot cast to... android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, inheritance, casting

I created some classes with inheritance concept, I have the main class for my application, that is called modulo, which corresponds to an module, and also some other classes called `moduloLedRGB`, `ModuloSwitch`, and `ModuloDimmer`, these 3 classes all extends the class modulo which has just the common arguments for modules like, id, name, Module type, and ipAdress. But, when I try to cast a module to one of those 3 childs classes I get an exception that says I cannot cast `Modulo` to `ModuloSitch` or `ModuloLedRGB`...

This is where I get the error:

```
switch (modulo.getModulo()){
             case "RGB":
                 ModuloLedRGB rgb = (ModuloLedRGB) modulo;
    rgb.setProgress(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("progress")));
    rgb.setProgressRed(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("progressRed")));
    rgb.setProgressGreen(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("progressGreen")));
    rgb.setProgressBlue(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("progressBlue")));
                            break;
                 case "Dimmer":
    ModuloDimmer dimmer = (ModuloDimmer) modulo;
    dimmer.setProgress(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("progress")));
                            break;
                        case"Switch":
                            ModuloSwitch sw = (ModuloSwitch) modulo;
                            break;
```

It says I cannot cast modulo that is an object corresponds to the class Modulo, to ModuloRGB.
getModulo returns a string that says me which kind of Module this is.

```
   package br.com.andrey.projetointegradoapp;

/**
 * Created by andrey on 04/08/2016.
 */
public class Modulo {
    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private String ModuleIpAdress;
    private String modulo;

    public String getModulo() {
        return modulo;
    }

    public void setModulo(String modulo) {
        this.modulo = modulo;
    }



    public String getModuleIpAdress() {
        return ModuleIpAdress;
    }

    public void setModuleIpAdress(String moduleIpAdress) {
        ModuleIpAdress = moduleIpAdress;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

This is the Modulo Class.

and this is ModuloLedRGB class:

```
 package br.com.andrey.projetointegradoapp;

/**
 * Created by andrey on 16/12/2016.
 */

public class ModuloLedRGB extends Modulo {
    private double progress;
    private double progressRed;
    private double progressGreen;
    private double progressBlue;

    public double getProgressRed() {
        return progressRed;
    }

    public void setProgressRed(double progressRed) {
        this.progressRed = progressRed;
    }


    public double getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public double getProgressGreen() {
        return progressGreen;
    }

    public void setProgressGreen(double progressGreen) {
        this.progressGreen = progressGreen;
    }

    public double getProgressBlue() {
        return progressBlue;
    }

    public void setProgressBlue(double progressBlue) {
        this.progressBlue = progressBlue;
    }
    }
```

Any ideas for why am I getting this exception? since the child extends the main class I think I should be able to cast it down, not?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error, or a runtime error?

Comment: You can do that    ModuloRgb objectModuloRgb  = new Modulo();

Comment: I'd use the instanceof operator, which is safe to bugs.

Comment: How was `modulo` created?  If it was created with `new ModuloLedRGB()` (or a subclass of `ModuloLedRGB`), then you can cast it to a `ModuloLedRGB`.  Otherwise you can't, and trying to cast will get you an exception at run time.

Comment: Shouldn't you set `modulo` to `"RGB"` somewhere? I did not find that in the code you have shown.

Comment: @shmosel it is a runtime error.

Comment: That means `modulo` is not an instance of `ModuloLedRGB`. The fact that `ModuloLedRGB` extends `Modulo` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mr.Popular but then i will create a new empty object, in this case i get the modules from a list that is returned by the internal database of my application.

Comment: @shmosel understand, that is true, its an instance of Modulo, i get this from a list returned by a method in sqlDAO.
there i have a instance of Modulo and then i put the values on the specific class, like this:  switch (modulo.getModulo()){
                        case "RGB":
                            ModuloLedRGB rgb = (ModuloLedRGB) modulo;

Comment: i do this casting issue also in the sql class because i have to populate the values of the specific objects also, modulo.getModulo returns a string that says which kind of Modulo it is

Comment: @ajb it is created from Modulo, when i create this i choose the kind of module and give all the atributes, but i cast it to RgbModulo to have acess to the specific attributes

Comment: @Henry, to convert Modulo to ModuloRgb i just cast it like this ModuloRgb rgb = (ModuloRgb)Modulo; i think it is better to have distinct classes to define ModuloRgb and ModuloSwitch, but they have some attributes in common so i decided to have this parent class that contains the common atributes for Modulo and i also have to show them all in the same list, and for this im using the same adapter to call even a Rgb Module view or a Switch Module view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears that you misunderstand the nature of casting.

When you say

```
class Modulo { ... }

class ModuloLedRGB extends Modulo { ... }
```

Subclassing defines an **is-a** relationship; every `ModuloLedRGB` is also a `Modulo`.  But that doesn't work both ways.

If you create an object with

```
new Modulo()
```

then it is a `Modulo`, but not a `ModuloLedRGB`.  If you create it with

```
new ModuloLedRGB()
```

it is both a `ModuloLedRGB` and a `Modulo`.  Saying it's a `Modulo` means that you can assign a variable of type `Modulo` to it, or use it as a `Modulo` parameter:

```
ModuloLedRGB x = new ModuloLedRGB();
Modulo y = x;  // this is legal, but the object's class doesn't change
```

`y` is a *reference* to the `ModuloLedRGB` object.  But note that although `y` is declared as `Modulo`, it still refers to the same object, whose class is `ModuloLedRGB`, because that's the way the object is created.

That's why you can use downcasting.  Say you later use the expression

```
(ModuloLedRGB)y
```

At this point, the compiler knows only that `y` (if not null) is a `Modulo`; it could be an object of class `Modulo`, `ModuloLedRGB`, `ModuloSwitch`, or anything else.  So at run time, the code checks to see what kind of object it's actually referring to.  Since the example above set `y` to an object created as a `ModuloLedRGB`, the cast is successful.  But if `y` were set to some other object that wasn't a `ModuloLedRGB`, the cast throws an exception.

This cast doesn't change an object, and it doesn't create a new object.  It just says "Make sure the object is of class `ModuloLedRGB`, and then treat it as a `ModuloLedRGB` so that we can access methods and instance variables that are particular to a `ModuloLedRGB`".

It looks, however, that you're trying to *convert* the object by changing its class.  You've created an object whose class is `Modulo`, and you're trying to come up with some new object whose class is `ModuloLedRGB`.  You can't do that with a cast.  If you have a `Modulo` and you want to create a `ModuloLedRGB`, you will have to *create a new object* with `new ModuloLedRGB()`, somewhere.  One common way to do this is to write a constructor:

```
class ModuloLedRGB extends Modulo {

    public ModuloLedRGB(Modulo m, maybe other parameters) {
        // copy the instance variables from "m"
        this.field = m.field;
        this.anotherField = m.anotherField;
        // set the new instance variables
        this.newField = maybe a parameter or some other computation;
        ...
    }
```

or write a static factory method to create a new `ModuloLedRGB` from a `Modulo`.  But you'll have to create it, and you'll have to write the code to create it.  You can't "convert" it from a `Modulo`.  There's no such thing in Java.

Comment: that's it, i think i undestand the problem, so if i want to use a ModuloLedRGB i have to make new ModuloLedRGB(); but i cant use it if i make new Modulo(); just the oposite is valid. i have this method in my database that returns all the Modulos of my system, in this method i create a new Modulo then set some attributes, switch case the kind of Modulo and in each case i'm casting it for ModuloLedRGB but it is a Modulo not ModuloLedRGB. i'm new on the O.O. world thank you for your help, i will try some changes...

Comment: ... i think i can first create a new Modulo(); check which type of Module it is, and in each case create a new ModuloLedRGB or what else, set the specifics attributes and then cast it to cast it to Modulo again to add on the list, am i losing any data with this transaction? or should i maybe have different methods on my database class for each different kind of Module on my system?

Comment: "I have this method in my database that returns all the Modulos of my system"--typically, a method like this could return some objects of class `ModuloLedRGB`, `ModuloSwitch`, or other objects of other subclasses.  A `Modulo[]` or `Set<Modulo>` or `List<Modulo>` or other collection will often have elements of different `Modulo` subclasses--that's how `Modulo` works.  But you do have to create them with the right class when you create them.  It is _not_ typical OO to create objects of the base class (`Modulo`) and try to get the actual class right later......

Comment: in fact, in a situation like yours, it would be more common to make `Modulo` an _abstract_ class so that you **can't** directly say `new Modulo()` but you would be required to create using a subclass.